# Triggers involving two tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have two relations(tables) namely and 'department' and 'employee'

```
create table department(depno numeric(5),depname varchar2(10),deplocation varchar2(7));
create table employee(empno numeric(5),empname varchar2(20),designation varchar2(20),depno numeric(5));
```

I'm trying to write a database trigger before deleting each row on table department deletes
corresponding department employees from employee table..
My code looks like

```
create or replace trigger tri before delete on department for each row
begin
delete from employee where depno=:old.depno;
end;
```

I inserted few data into my relation and tried to delete one of them having the depno as 2
'''delete from department where depno=2;'''
But it shows an error like this

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.T1' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

**Can you please help me with this or provide me an alternative solution to this problem?**

Comment: Why not simply define a foreign key with `on delete cascade`

Comment: (1) Is your trigger named `tri` or `T1`? (2) In order to see trigger compile errors, after you create a trigger and it says "completed with compile errors", you can run `show errors`

Comment: A FK is the correct approach, but think about the business rule this establishes. It essentially says "If I delete the department fire all the employees". Maybe instead of "on delete cascade" you want "on delete set null"

Comment: Why is trigger T1 in the "SYSTEM" schema? Is that where you created your application objects? That could also be part of the problem, as SYSTEM is reserved for Oracle-provided stuff and should NEVER be used for application objects. If there's something wrong there, then there could be an issue with your whole database instance. Please clarify which schema owns your tables and trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time,friends.. I have created a trigger named t1 previously and something was wrong with that.. I dropped the trigger t1 and it works perfectly now